# Query SQL database from within Manipulate in cdf?

Tags: sql, enterprise-cdf

As example, the following very simple code works fine when I run it from Mathematica .nb, but fails to get the data from SQL when I create an (Enterprise) cdf from it:

```
Manipulate[
 hadb = SQLExecute[conn, "SELECT * FROM HV_refs", 
   "ShowColumnHeadings" -> True];
 idx = Position[hadb, ref][[1, 1]];
 abr = hadb[[idx, 2]];
 bcr = hadb[[idx, 3]];
 cdr = hadb[[idx, 4]];
 adr = hadb[[idx, 5]];
 Grid[{{" ", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"}, {ref, abr, bcr, cdr, adr}}, 
  Frame -> All],
 {{ref, hadb[[2, 1]], "Choose ref."}, hadb[[All, 1]], 
  ControlType -> PopupMenu},
 Initialization :> {Needs["DatabaseLink`"];
   conn = OpenSQLConnection["Mathematica_test_db"]}]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where is `"Mathematica_test_db"`?

Comment: Is available on a SQL server in our intranet (share place)...

Comment: Maybe `DatabaseResourcesPath` is different in the player. (just guessing, have not tired that)

Comment: Ok, how can I check that in CDF Player?

Comment: You can `CDFDeploy @ Dynamic[{DateString[], DatabaseResourcesPath[]}, UpdateInterval ->1]` and check what does it show in the player.

Comment: You mean like: `Manipulate[
 CDFDeploy@
  Dynamic[{DateString[], DatabaseResourcesPath[]}, 
   UpdateInterval -> 1],
 Initialization :> {Needs["DatabaseLink`"]}] ` , exported as .cdf and run in CDF Player ?

Comment: No, I mean what I wrote. Then open deployed cdf and check what does it show.

Comment: Yes, I did that, but I get: `CDFDeploy: CDFDeploy called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected. ` and  `CDFDeploy[\!\(\*
DynamicBox[ToBoxes[{
DateString[], 
$CellContext`DatabaseResourcesPath[]}, StandardForm],
ImageSizeCache->{351., {3., 9.}},
UpdateInterval->1]\)] `

Comment: Right, sorry, I forgot you need to add cdf name or path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56524/discussion-between-conrad-and-kuba).

Comment: It seems that it works though, if I provide the full information in the OpenSQLConnection, like `conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)", ***], "Version" -> ***, "Location" -> ***, "Name" -> ***, "Password" -> ***, ]` etc. However, in Mathematica I have to evaluate the cell about 3 times in order to get it work, the first 2 times I get errors, as the data was not yet arrived from the database... How can I tell Mathematica to wait until the data from SQL server has arrived?

Comment: So `OpenSQLConnection` call is asynchronous and you can do other things before the data is there?

Comment: The OpenSQLConnection needs some time to establish the connection to fatabase and retrieve data. Although I put it in `Initialization`, Manipulate doesn't wait for it, finds no data and generates error messages and stops. If I re-evaluate the code, only the 3rd time it works...